# responding to java checked exception with lambda to notify user

Tags: java, android, exception

During debugging etc, I'd love to have a short and easy way to make all my unexpected errors result in a dialog box with the complete stack trace before crashing. While this can be done with a try/catch block and the self-control to actually write it out each time, I'd rather have something I can add with just a few characters, like:

```
notifyOnFail(() -> new FileInputStream("noneThere!"));
```

I'm trying to adapt [this method](https://www.rainerhahnekamp.com/en/ignoring-exceptions-in-java/) for bypassing the javac checked exception requirement into a method I can add to my activity. But I don't understand lambda syntax well enough to make it happen.

His idea is that you can write a lambda expression for handing the exception, rather than inserting a boilerplate try/catch {} around your code. My goal is similar except I want it to produce a dialog box with the stack trace before the runtime exception is raised. Here's a working version of his code that throws a RuntimeException.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface mkRunTime<T> {
  T execute() throws Exception;

  public static <T> T e(mkRunTime<T> runtime) {
    try {
      return runtime.execute();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
  }
}
```

and then it's used like this:

```
mkRunTime.e(() -> new FileInputStream("this file obviously doesn't exist, and I'd like to know that's why my program is crashing"));
```

So how can I make this into a method of my activity instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'll use `Supplier` from the standard library for this example. Let's say you have method with such signature:

```
static <T> T getSupplierResult(Supplier<T> supplier) {
  return supplier.get();
}
```

Naturally the supplier you provide can't throw exceptions. Now you need a functional interface declared to throw exceptions.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ThrowingSupplier<T> {

  T get() throws Exception;
}
```

Then you have to transform this throwing supplier into the standard one. With a method it will look like this:

```
static <T> Supplier<T> wrapThrowingSupplierAsSupplier(ThrowingSupplier<T> throwingSupplier) {
  return () -> {
    try {
      return throwingSupplier.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  };
}
```

Note that this method returns `Supplier<T>`, **not** `T`.

If you are not used to used to lambdas, the same can be achieved with a standard class:

```
private static final class ThrowingSupplierWrapper<T> implements Supplier<T> {

  private final ThrowingSupplier<T> throwingSupplier;

  ThrowingSupplierWrapper(ThrowingSupplier<T> throwingSupplier) {
    this.throwingSupplier = throwingSupplier;
  }

  @Override
  public T get() {
    try {
      return throwingSupplier.get();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
      throw new RuntimeException(exc);
    }
  }
}
```

And the invocations of the method which requires `Supplier`:

```
getSupplierResult(wrapThrowingSupplierAsSupplier(() -> new FileInputStream("qwerty")));
getSupplierResult(wrapThrowingSupplierAsSupplier(() -> new FileInputStream("faceroll")));
```

Or using the class:

```
getSupplierResult(new ThrowingSupplierWrapper<>(() -> new FileInputStream("asd")));
```

Comment: that's a pretty verbose invocation. If that's the simplest java allows then a static weak reference to my main activity seems like a better solution.

Comment: @AlRo The invocation is literary 1 additional inlined method, if you go with this approach. I'd hardly call that verbose, considering you have to transform one thing into something else, 1 additional operation is the minimum. If you want to make the wrapping method shorter, you can research into lomboks' `@SneakyThrows`, but personally wouldn't add entire library just for that(unless you are already using it).